# Diffeomorphism maps geodesics to geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $f:M \to N$ a diffeomorphism between riemannian manifolds of the same dimension. What are sufficient conditions for $f$ to map geodesics to geodesics? Of course, if $f$ is an isometry this occurs, but I am looking for weaker conditions.

Comment: Do you know of an example of such an $f$  on a compact manifold $M$ which is NOT an isometry?

Comment: If you scale $\mathbb R^n$ and restrict to the sphere you get such a map

Answer (score 4):

In general, there are manifolds with self-diffeomorphisms which map geodesics to geodesics, but are not isometries. For instance, any affine map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e multiplication by a constant matrix) does this.

See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15805/are-isometries-the-only-geodesic-preserving-maps-in-a-cat0-space).

Comment: Another example is the Klein model of the hyperbolic space: Hyperbolic geodesics map to euclidean geodesics.