# Is every geodesic-preserving map of the sphere an isometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, symmetry, isometry, geodesic, spherical-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional unit sphere, equipped with the standard round Riemannian metric.

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ be a diffeomorphism and suppose that for every (parametrized) geodesic $\gamma$, $f \circ \gamma$ is also a (parametrized) geodesic.

Must $f$ be an isometry? (that is the restriction of an orthogonal matrix on $\text{O}(n+1)$).

---

An equivalent condition on $f$ is that $\nabla df=0$ where $\nabla=\nabla^{(T\mathbb{S}^n)^*} $ $ \otimes \nabla^{f^*T\mathbb{S}^n}$ is the relevant tensor product connection.

Comment: Is there any counterexample if we consider diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$ with same properties? ($M$ is closed arbitrary manifold). A [related old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785565/272127)

Comment: Thanks, this was my next natural question. I asked about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896934/is-every-geodesic-preserving-diffeomorphism-an-isometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such an $f$ must be an isometry.

Let $p\in S^n$, $v\in T_p S^n$ with $v\neq 0$.  By polarization, it is enough to show that  that $\|d_p f(v)\|= \|v\|$.

So, let's establish this equality.  To do so, first note that $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^n$ defined by $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(tv)$ is injective on $\left[0,\frac{2\pi}{\|v\|}\right)$.

Because $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f\circ\gamma$ is injective on the same interval.  But since $f$ maps geodesics to geodesics, we know $f\circ \gamma = \exp_{f(p)}(td_p f(v))$.  This implies that $\|d_p f(v)\| \leq \|v\|.$

Further, because $\gamma$ fails to be injective on $\left[0, \frac{2\pi}{\|v\|}\right]$, the same must be true of $f\circ \gamma$.  This implies that $\|d_pf(v)\| \geq \|v\|$.  The two inequalities together now give the result.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure I understand: Are you in fact showing that for every $v \in T_pM$ which corresponds to a periodic geodesic, $||df_p(v)||=||v||$? (not just on the sphere.)

Comment: Actually, on a second thought, I think that your argument uses the fact that all the "closed geodesic loops" have the same length, right? you are using that $\gamma$ and $f \circ \gamma$ stop minimizing after the same time/length.

Comment: Yes, to the second point.

Comment: @JasonDeVito The key argument, as noticed Asaf Shachar, seems to be that all geodesics are closed and have the same length. Would this mean that if $(M,g)$ is a Zoll manifold with all geodesics of the same length (I once read it as "Besse manifold"), then this result is also true?

Comment: @DIdier_:  That certainly seems to be the case.

Comment: @DIdier_: Just a comment: "Besse" has another book with this title: [Manifolds all of whose Geodesics are Closed](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61876-5). and Zoll’s Surfaces is in chapter 4.

Comment: @C.F.G Now that I remember it, I heard the name "Besse manifold" in a talk in which the orator said he called these manifolds Besse as a tribute to this book. Thank you for the reference.