# Is every geodesic-preserving diffeomorphism an isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, isometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a closed $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.

Let $f:M \to M$ be a diffeomorphism and suppose that for every (parametrized) geodesic $\gamma$, $f \circ \gamma$ is also a (parametrized) geodesic.

Must $f$ be an isometry?

An equivalent condition on $f$ is that $\nabla df=0$ where $\nabla=\nabla^{T^*M} $ $ \otimes \nabla^{f^*TM}$ is the relevant tensor product connection.

Note that this equivalent assumption implies that $df$ has constant singular values, and in particular that the Jacobian $\det(df)$ is constant, hence it must be $1$ (since $f$ was assumed to be a diffeomorphism.) Thus $f$ is volume-preserving.

---

This can certainly be false for manifolds with nonempty boundary in general, as the following example shows:

Let $0<a<b$, and set
$
M=D_{a,b}=\biggl\{(x,y) \,\biggm | \, \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1 \biggr\}
$
to be the ellipse with diameters $a,b$, endowed with the standard Euclidean metric (induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$). Then there exists $A \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R) \setminus \operatorname{SO}(2)$ such that $AD_{a,b}=D_{a,b}$, and $A$ clearly preserves geodesics (it maps straight lines to straight lines.)

Indeed one can take $A$ to be of the form
$$
A =A_{\theta}:=  \begin{pmatrix} a& 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1/a& 0 \\ 0 & 1/b \end{pmatrix}=
 \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\frac ab \sin\theta \\ \frac ba \sin\theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}.
$$

---

For $M=\mathbb{S}^n $ the answer is positive, by this [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895639/104576).

Comment: This was discussed several times, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301858/could-a-riemannian-metric-be-uniquely-determined-by-its-exponential-map/3614249#3614249 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132244/can-one-recover-a-metric-from-geodesics/357025#357025

Comment: Thanks, these are very nice discussions! Just to be sure: the connection between these question and mine is that my assumption on $f$ is equivalent to the statement that $g,f^*g$ have the same geodesics, right?

Comment: Right, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. As a counterexample, take the torus $\mathbb{T}^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is endowed with the Euclidean metric. Since linear maps preserve geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ acts by geodesic-preserving diffeomorphisms on $\mathbb{T}^n$, and many of these are not isometries. For example, consider the map $\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x+y)$ modulo $1$.

Qualitatively speaking, the requirements on $f$ do not constrain the shear components of $df$, though I suppose there may be global or even local obstructions to the existence of such shear maps.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! I have one question: is it true that every geodesic-preserving diffeomorphism of the flat torus is induced by an element of $GL_n(Z)$?

Comment: @AsafShachar: That's right. You can deduce this, for instance, from the fundamental theorem of projective geometry, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035287/is-a-function-which-preserves-zero-and-affine-lines-necessarily-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1